# Bit of advice regarding navigation with tableviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, tableview

Ok so background info is that i am trying to produce a web tree style menu of options for use within a current app. Each item has a code and a parent code. (so e.g. Parent code: Car / code: Ford, Parent code: Ford / Code: Mondeo etc.etc.etc.
I have the data stored in Core Data and i currently have it so it performs an NSFetch for the first option (Car), then uses the code from that option(Ford) to look for the next level but this doesn't do the side swipe that Apple tableview menus are so well known for SO...

I'm not sure whether to try and extract the data into an Array of Arrays somehow and then the menu should scroll through properly OR have a 2nd view that will load the next option in the background and then swap view controllers on didSelectRowAtIndexPath...

If you could point me towards any sample code/tutorials/information regarding these as well would be great. I've googled/checked apple docs and the 'Navigating a Data Hierarchy with Table Views' apple dev uses storyboards whereas this app doesn't. The only info i could find on extracting core data to an array of arrays was on here and was related to CSV files which i do not need.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opted to use 2 views in a UIScrollView, disable the user scrolling option and scrolling across (Then swapping the views over with no animation) to create an infinite limit of scrolls =]